# Is it possible to show a loading bar in ASP.net while all resources are loading

Tags: c#, asp.net

If I am creating a very graphically intensive web page, is there a possible way to Load all of my images, and sounds before displaying any of it?  So that way once the images and sounds are loaded, I dont wan't weaker connections to get choppy noises or half loaded images

Comment: You should rather tag this question with HTML and/or JavaScript. It's bearly related to ASP.NET, and completely not related to C#.

Comment: I cant see how, asp.net is a web development platform that uses C# or vb.net to program web functionality.  Which is exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: ASP.NET and C# are "part" of the server-side environment. Showing a loading overlay and "preloading" or bulk-loading images is IMHO related to client-side techniques. I'm not an ASP.NET expert, but can hardly imagine if server-side at all has any relevance in your question. Server is just responding to requests, it's up to the client to decide how to render, what to show, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the image part only, you can encode all the images into base64 strings, this way all the images would be ready by the time the page is loaded. Do note that by doing so you are not making use of browser's cache feature since all images have to be loaded each time.

If you want both sound and image to be ready by the time page loads, you can return an empty page or a loading screen with a loader javascript to do the loading, and then ajax the real page after loading is done (browser will cache them for reuse)